# How can I differentiate Safari and Chrome in CSS?

Tags: css, browser

I know I can use conditional CSS to differentiate webkit browsers from others, but it is my understanding that both chrome and safari are webkit browsers. How would I differentiate between the two? There is a safari specific fix that makes chrome pixelate the Nivo Slider when it gets small, and I need to get this working for both browsers.

The Safari fix is:

```
img{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

My Conditional Code is:

```
[if Webkit] img {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome isn't webkit anymore. Google dropped it last year and made its own (Blink).

Comment: @Aibrean -webkit- tags still work in latest chrome

Comment: So I found that I don't need to do this after all (The code doesn't seem to make a difference in chrome, so I have the problem anyway), but knowing how to distinguish between chrome and safari may be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript, this code fragment will distinguish Safari from Chrome:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    $('html').addClass('safari-only');
}
```

For a CSS-only hack, try this (don't know if it works):

```
/* Safari only */
.myClass:not(:root:root) { 
}
```

For your specific case, with **JavaScript**:

JS:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    $('img').addClass('safari-only');
}
```

CSS:

```
img.safari-only {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**CSS only**:

```
img:not(:root:root) {
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a CSS-only hack and the one you suggested doesn't seem to work. =/