# CSS rotateX rotates reverse in Chrome than Safari, IE, Edge, Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, css-transforms

I'm trying to add an animation on enter that looks like a slot machine spinning. My problem is I want all the numbers rotating from the bottom to the top. This fiddler works in all browsers but chrome. Chrome spins the numbers from top to bottom.

If I add the -webkit- prefix then it reverses it in Safari. Any ideas?

Essentially I'm trying to keyframe from

```
transform: rotateX(-72deg) translateZ(20px);
```

to

```
transform: rotateX(72deg) translateZ(20px);
```

[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/trLh04h4/6/)

Comment: The start and end states in your question are the same. Furthermore, they don't match your Fiddler demo...

Comment: That was edited seconds after I posted. I don't know when stackoverflow updates so others can see. The transform is from -72deg to 72deg. Look at the fiddler for more details.

Answer (score -1):

According to [How can I differentiate Safari and Chrome in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560862/how-can-i-differentiate-safari-and-chrome-in-css) you need javascript to test for the user agent in effect inject a safari-only class or in your case a chrome only.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) {
  $('.carousel').addClass('chrome-only');
}
```